# Decrypt data in React Native project

Tags: react-native, encryption

Expected output : "halo;world:78221199"
output i get : s:19:"halo;world;78221199";
why i get s:19:...; ?

here my code i use

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { atob } from 'js-base64';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const base64Key = 'zHB2DJ2OhHkFPBUAqkD6NZiz1T0s3VuycW1HaRnzPIc=';

const Decrypt = () => {
    const [decryptedData, setDecryptedData] = useState('');
    

    useEffect(() => {
        decryptData();
    }, []);

    const decryptData = () => {
        try {
            const encryptedData = 'eyJpdiI6IjcrbGxhdGVYV1F0bit5T3M3VU5CN0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVDltMmhnYU8xcTFPakhQUEZZNE5mWmpMNkdEbEFoOUgzSEl0cGJwdXRFVT0iLCJtYWMiOiJjNjAxMjdkYjU3MjVhOGE3NjFmMGU1MzVhYWM4ZmRmNDRiMGExN2ExMDQzOGU1M2Y0YmE3NzE2MDQ4OWM0ZjA0IiwidGFnIjoiIn0=';
            const decodedData = atob(encryptedData);
            console.log(decodedData)
            const { iv, value, mac, tag } = JSON.parse(decodedData);
            console.log(iv);

            const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64Key);
            const decryptedValue = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {
                iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv),
                // mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                // padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
            }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            console.log(decryptedValue);

            setDecryptedData(decryptedValue);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Decryption error:', error);
            setDecryptedData('Decryption error');
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text>Decrypted Data: </Text>
                <Text style={{ color: 'red', marginLeft: 4 }}>{decryptedData}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Decrypt;
```

somebody help me

data : eyJpdiI6Im5qQTNHbWZwUlpCR1YrK2VhRGJuZVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibW1aVE5qWmI3cjlDendMSTR3bCtNN2RpM0hKRmpVM0FML3RYazJoc3ZQYWVaRHp1L2JkNlgwWE9VWmFzRVJqYSIsIm1hYyI6IjBiNTE0NGQyM2UxZGNmNTgyYzk0YTEzMGVjMmRhZDY4NjQ0NDA0ZDgwY2FkNmMzYjU2MTlhMDYzYjMxNmEwNDEiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==

key : xp+EtmX14oXQMT6AAOnztGU4dRH8OY6YqxkEknmkziw=

expected result : "halo;world:78221199"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why i get s:19:...; ?

The answer is: because it was encrypted that way. I.e. you have to inspect or post the encryption code to answer your question.

A possible explanation is that PHP was used for encryption and the plaintext was serialized before with [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), in any case your `s:19:"...;"` strongly reminds of the [PHP serialization format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_serialization_format).

In this case the deserialization can be done with [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). With the help of the [*locutus*](https://github.com/locutusjs/locutus) project PHP functionalities (like `unserialize()`) can be provided in JavaScript. This way you could deserialize the data:

```js
import unserialize from 'locutus/php/var/unserialize.js'
...
console.log(unserialize(decryptedValue)); // halo;world;78221199
```